# Align text below RadioButton

Tags: android, android-layout, android-radiobutton

I need to align text below `RadioButton` by this `RadioButton` text, not by `RadioButton` icon. Can i get it without using hard margin?

Example:
[image]

My code below:

```
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/llcontainer"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/half_keyline"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <RadioButton
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="text1"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show us your layout file so we can help you in the best possible way, which parent holds radio buttonand text, etc...

Comment: it is just LinearLayout with RadioButton inside

Comment: You could use a custom button (with a known size) for the RadioButton checkmark. Then use the same width for the left margin of the TextView.

Comment: Is it worth it to change built-in radio by my own? I can do it but i think it's not the best solution

Comment: Do you have a better idea?

Comment: No, that's why I'm here lol

Comment: Use a RelativeLayout and its align attributes.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llcontainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="text1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<RadioButton
     android:id="@+id/Icon1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:button="@android:color/transparent"
     android:drawablePadding="-20dp"
     android:drawableTop="@drawable/your_Image_Here"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:text="text1" />
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rbtn"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="text1"/>

                     <  TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/text1"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/rbtn" <!-- this here -->
                        android:text="@string/hello_world"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
```